# Cannot insert into a time-series collection in a multi-document transaction

Tags: mongodb, session, time-series

I want to copy data of a device to another device by uuid, and collection to copy is timeseries collection in mongo. So I write a function like below code:

```
function copyData(fromUuid, toUuid) {
  const session = db.getMongo().startSession();
  session.startTransaction({
    readConcern: { level: 'snapshot' },
    writeConcern: { w: 'majority' },
  });
  const db = session.getDatabase('dbName');
  const deviceCollection = tsngDb.timeseriesDevices;

  const devices = [];
  deviceCollection.find({ 'm.uuid': fromUuid }).forEach((device) => {
    device.m.uuid = toUuid;
    delete device._id;
    devices.push(device);
  });
  deviceCollection.insertMany(devices);

  session.commitTransaction();
}

let lsData = [
  {
    fromUuid: '123',
    toUuid: '456',
  },
];
lsData.forEach(({ fromUuid, toUuid }) => {
  copyData(fromUuid, toUuid);
});
```

actually, I have to copy some collections, but have only this collection is timeseries, so I want to use session to make sure all processes is done before session has been commited.

But mongo throw error:

**time-series insert failed: dbName.timeseriesDevices :: caused by :: Cannot insert into a time-series collection in a multi-document transaction: dbName.timeseriesDevices**

Comment: see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/current/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/#transactions explicitly forbids it:

> You cannot write to time series collections in transactions.

At least in current latest v7.

There is no explanation but I reckon there must be some good reasons to explicitly disable it. In the code https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/bf95ed7e9d03fdf19c9633a463c7c7565128a734/src/mongo/db/ops/write_ops_exec.cpp#L2948:

```
write_ops::InsertCommandReply performTimeseriesWrites(.....) {
    ......
    uassert(ErrorCodes::OperationNotSupportedInTransaction,
            str::stream() << "Cannot insert into a time-series collection in a multi-document "
                             "transaction: "
                          << ns(request).toStringForErrorMsg(),
            !opCtx->inMultiDocumentTransaction());
```

Comment: To add some context here: a timeseries collection is really just a view.  The data is actually stored in a different collection with "bucket" in the name.  Each document in the "bucket" collection can contain thousands of time series records in a compressed format, which appear as individual documents when queried via the timeseries collection.  Just try to puzzle out how locking would have to work in order to permit multiple multi-document transactions and other uses simultaneously, and you'll see the problems.